# Display JSON data in table format with a submit button corresponding to each row

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

/* How do I Display json data into a table in a JSP Page with a submit button in each row. On clicking submit button, Row data should be sent to a servlet.

I have fetched json data from a Servlet using Ajax.

Below is my ajax call to get JSON data from Servlet */

```
function updateprofile(){
$.ajax({
url : 'abc/ConnectionInfo',
type: 'GET',
data: {},
data type: 'json'
}).done(function (data){
     renderProfiles(data);
}).fail(function (){
toaster.error("Eror...");
});
}

function 
renderProfiles(data){

//How can I implement this 
method to display all the 
data in table format with a 
button corresponding to 
each row.  And on clicking 
of the button it should 
send a profile ID to 
Servlet Post method.
}
```

Comment: post your json data as well which you are getting from servlet in ajax call

Comment: [{"metric":"connected[qa_KCDz->Exre]"},"metric":"connected[qa_KTDz->Exre]"},"metric":"connected[qa_KPDz->Exre]"}]

Comment: @Swati I have posted the json data. I want to display "connected[qa_KCDz->Exre]" part in a table row and when user click its corresponding button. Let's Say button in first row then  "qa_KCDz"  should go to Servlet post method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.foreach` loop to iterate your json data and show them in your table. Demo code(you need to do changes in below code as per your requirment) :

```js
//your json data
var response = [{
    "metric": "connected[qa_KCDz->Exre]"
  },
  {
    "metric": "connected[qa_KTDz->Exre]"
  },
  {
    "metric": "connected[qa_KPDz->Exre]"
  }
];

var str = '<table border=1><tr>\n' +
  '<th>Something</th>\n' +
  '<th>Submit</th>\n' +
  '</tr>';
  //looping through json data
$.each(response, function(key, value) {
  //get value
  var s = value['metric'];
  //getting index of [
  var i = s.indexOf('[');
  var data = s.slice(10, i + 8).trim();

  str += '<td>' + value['metric'] + '</td>';
  str += '<td> <form method="post" action="servletname"><input type="hidden" name="data" value=' + data + ' ><input type="submit" value ="send" ></form></td></tr>';


});
str += "</table>";

//appending data
$("#table").html(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table"> </div>
```

Put above code of jquery under your `function renderProfiles(data){..}`.Also,under `<form></form>` tag i have added a `hidden` input field with the required value that you need to send to your servlet .Get that value  using `request.getParameter("data")` in `doPost` method of servlet.

Comment: Yay !!! It worked.. Thank You so much for your help and quick response.

Comment: Hey @Swati .Do you know how can we implement it using Ajax and not using form so that page doesn't redirect.

Comment: Assign the `data-id="+data+"` which has the required value in `button` tag and use `onclick` event of jquery get the value of button using `$(this).attr("data-id")` and passed the same using ajax.

Comment: str += '<td> <button type="submit" data-id=" + data +" onclick="submit connection()">Reconnect</button></td></tr>';

Comment: function submitcinnection() { debugger; $.ajax({ url : 'abc/reconnect', type:'POST', dataType : 'json' , content type : 'application/json; charset=utf-8', data: JSON.stringify({data : $(this).attr("data-id)}),

Comment: data is not passing to Servlet. Can you please help where am I making mistake.

Comment: check if the `$(this).attr("data-id)` giving you required value or not ,Also does your browser console shows any `error` ?  Also try like this `$(this).data("id");` .

Comment: Hi Swati. Need a help. I have a webpage which has multiple Tabs. And I added above feature in a new tab(Connection) using above jQuery. When I am clicking on my tab I can see all the data but after clicking on my tab when I go back to another tab, all the data disappears from another tab. I have to refresh complete page again to get back the contents of other tabs. Can you please help

Comment: can you post another question with detail explanation of your problem , i will assist you there ? currently without seeing code i can't suggest you anything..?

Comment: Is there any slack group or other means where I can send you the Screenshot of the code?

Comment: https://join.slack.com/t/javajquery/shared_invite/zt-e1m9g9ut-vCUC5XO~ZflsiINUNapHuw

Comment: Can you please connect in slack?